# Poisson Equation with variable coefficients and mixed boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I try to solve the Poisson equation with variable coefficients with mixed boundary condition in 2D([2,3]x[2,3], I did:

```
 ClearAll[y, x1, x2];
  a = x1 + x2;
  pde = D[a D[y[x1, x2], x1], x1] + D[a D[y[x1, x2], x2], x2] - 2;
  bc = {y[x1, 2] == 2 + x1, y[x1, 3] == 3 + x1};
  sol = NDSolve[{pde == 
  NeumannValue[-1*a, x1 == 2] + NeumannValue[1*a, x1 == 3], bc}, 
    y, {x1, 2, 3}, {x2, 2, 3}]

  Plot3D[Evaluate[y[x1, x2] /. sol], {x1, 2, 3}, {x2, 2, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x1", "X2", "y[x1,x2]"}, 
  BaseStyle -> 12]
```

The exact solution y=x1+x2, however, the results not provide high accuracy.

Comment: Your boundary condititions and NeumannValue both lie on the same boundaries `x2==2` and `x3==3` !!! That's why Mathematica ignores the Neumanncondition.

Comment: Thank you Ulrich, I modified the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the FEM method it is good to cast your equations into coefficient form as shown [FEM Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1222366601).

$$\frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {t^2}}}u + d\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}u + \nabla \cdot\left( { - c\nabla u - \alpha u + \gamma } \right) + \beta \cdot\nabla u + au - f = 0$$

When you use the coefficient form, there generally is a nice one-to-one mapping with other FEM codes such as COMSOL.

The Poisson only contains a diffusive plus a load or source term

$$\nabla \cdot\left( { - c\nabla u} \right) - f = 0$$

The `HeatTransferModel` function in the [Heat Transfer Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html) will generate the Poisson equation if you specify a positive "volumetric" source, $f$,  like so:

```
ClearAll[HeatTransferModel]
HeatTransferModel[T_, X_List, k_, ρ_, Cp_, Velocity_, Source_] :=
  Module[{V, Q, a = k}, 
  V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 
    0, ρ*Cp*Velocity.Inactive[Grad][T, X]];
  Q = If[Source === "NoSource", 0, Source];
  If[FreeQ[a, _?VectorQ], a = a*IdentityMatrix[Length[X]]];
  If[VectorQ[a], a = DiagonalMatrix[a]];
  (*Note the-sign in the operator*)
  a = PiecewiseExpand[Piecewise[{{-a, True}}]];
  Inactive[Div][a.Inactive[Grad][T, X], X] + V - Q]
pop = HeatTransferModel[y[x1, x2], {x1, x2}, k, ρ, Cp, "NoFlow", 
  f]
```

[image: Poisson equation]

The workflow following the guidance in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/224755/61809) would be:

```
(* User supplied definition *)
a = x1 + x2;
(* Create a Domain *)
Ω2D = Rectangle[{2, 2}, {3, 3}];
(* Create parametric PDE operator *)
pop = HeatTransferModel[y[x1, x2], {x1, x2}, k, ρ, Cp, "NoFlow", 
   f];
(* Replace k and f parameters *)
op = pop /. {k -> a, f -> -2};
(* Setup flux conditions *)
nv2 = NeumannValue[-1 a, x1 == 2];
nv3 = NeumannValue[1 a, x1 == 3];
(* Setup Dirichlet Conditions *)
dc2 = DirichletCondition[y[x1, x2] == 2 + x1, x2 == 2];
dc3 = DirichletCondition[y[x1, x2] == 3 + x1, x2 == 3];
(* Create PDE system *)
pde = {op == nv2 + nv3, dc2, dc3};
(* Solve and Plot *)
yfun = NDSolveValue[pde, y, {x1, x2} ∈ Ω2D]
Plot3D[Evaluate[yfun[x1, x2]], {x1, x2} ∈ Ω2D, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2", "y[x1,x2]"}, 
 BaseStyle -> 12]
```

[image: PDE Solution]

Again, you can see that the solution matches the exact solution.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{x1 + x2, yfun[x1, x2]}, {x1, 2, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x1", "y[x1,x2]"}, BaseStyle -> 12, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, 
    Directive[Green, Opacity[0.75], Thickness[0.015], Dashed]}], {x2, 
  2, 3}, ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image: Manipulate]

Comment: Many thanks Tim Laska, I highly appreciate your help, my problem was how to define a and f....Best regards

Comment: Dear Tim Laska, I have two questions please, 1) how many elements used in above FEM?2) Can we change the domain to say circle or other domain types, if yes, what shall we change only the domain?

Comment: @user62716 You are welcome.  To determine the number of elements, evaluate `yfun["ElementMesh"]`.  You will see that there are 400 Quad elements.  You can change the domain, but you will have to consider how the boundaries might change as well.  When the domains get complicated, you probably should consider [The Element Mesh Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html).  You can then use `ElementMarker` to define special boundaries.

Comment: Many thanks Dr.Tim....Best regards

Answer (score 3):

If you want `Function[{x1, x2}, x1 + x2]` to be the solution of a PDE, you probably want the following PDE:

```
ClearAll[y, x1, x2];
a = x1 + x2;
pde = -D[a D[y[x1, x2], x1], x1] - D[a D[y[x1, x2], x2], x2] + 2;
bc = {y[x1, 2] == 2 + x1, y[x1, 3] == 3 + x1};
Y = NDSolveValue[{pde == NeumannValue[-1*a, x1 == 2] + NeumannValue[1*a, x1 == 3], bc}, y, {x1, 2, 3}, {x2, 2, 3}]

Plot3D[{Y[x1, x2], x1 + x2}, {x1, 2, 3}, {x2, 2, 3}, PlotRange -> All,
  AxesLabel -> {"x1", "X2", "y[x1,x2]"}, BaseStyle -> 12]
```

[image]

There were three issues: the place of the Neumann condition as pointed out by Ulrich, the fact that `-4` was a wrong choice for the mass-term, and the sign issue from your previous post.

Comment: @user62716, please also have a look at [this section about the verification of solutions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#754253806) in the documentation.

Comment: Dear Henrif, you are right for f=2, move to left side will be -2, but the sign of Laplace operator I want it +....thanks

Comment: I want to use the code suggested by Tim in my previous question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/224755/62716

Comment: @user62716 Of course you are free to flip the signs of the `NeumannValue`s instead. But in FEM for elliptic PDE one writes the equations typically so that the highest order term is _positive definite_. And $y \mapsto \mathrm{div} (a \, \mathrm{grad} \, y)$ is _negative definite_ for $a>0$. In the end of the day, it's your choice. I just tried to show you that you are using some wrong signs at some places: $y(x_1,x_2) = x_1 + x_2$ is just not the analytic solution of the equation that you told _Mathematica_ to solve. So please don't complain _because you are using it in the wrong way_.

Comment: Thank you Henrik.....